# Java assertion getting mangled with Weblogic and Struts 2

Tags: java, weblogic, assert

I started using assertions in my Java EE 5 app and while the assert is working, the stack trace and messages are not.  Here is my code:

```
  assert 4 == outputList.size() : "outputList is not size 4: " + outputList.size();
```

When I make the list size 3 it throws this:

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@6ea53502 - appName: 'MyPortal', name: 'myportal', context-path: '/myportal'] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:610)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:770)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:505)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3242)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2010)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1916)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
>
```

It does not do a clean stack trace and does not have the assert message.

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you change the 1st part to `assert outputList.size().equals(4)` ?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception that kills your App is caused by the assertion? It says NullPointerException, so if you think it happens there, check if the list is null.

Comment: Zach, the size() returns and int which cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: Jochen, no, I am not sure an assertion is being thrown.  But when I make compare the size of the list to 3 (which it is) there is no exception.

Comment: What is more about you stacktrace, I believe its root is not the `assert` life of code. is it?

Comment: I posted the entire stack trace.  It is possible the assert is causing an exception before it can do the message logging and regular assert stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the assert that throws that exception.
You can use `assert` key word, but JVM normally ignores it, if you want to make JVM not to ignore it you must use `java -enableassertions` or `java -ea`.

So you must add this java parameter to your JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: I am using -enableassertions.